# How to scrape between a series of same strings?

Tags: php, string, curl, extract

I have a function that scrapes data from a webpage. I choose the tags where the data should be scraped and I can get the results. The function.php is like that:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/HTML; charset=utf-8" />

<?php

function LoadCURLPage($url, $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4 Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)",
$cookie = '', $referer = '', $post_fields = '', $return_transfer = 1,
$follow_location = 1, $ssl = '', $curlopt_header = 0)
{
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

if($ssl)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
}

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $curlopt_header);

if($agent)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
}

if($post_fields)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


if($referer)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
}

if($cookie)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
}

$result = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

return $result;
}

function extract_unit($string, $start, $end)
{
$pos = stripos($string, $start);

$str = substr($string, $pos);

$str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));

$second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);

$str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);

$unit = trim($str_three); // remove whitespaces

return $unit;
}

?>
```

and the process.php is like that:

```
<?php

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

include 'function.php';

// Connect to this url using CURL

$url1 = 'http://www.remixon.com.tr/remixon.xml';


// Letâs use cURL to connect to the 

$data1 = LoadCURLPage($url1);


// Extract information between STRING 1 & STRING 2

$string_one1 = '<SatisFiyati>';
$string_two1 = '</SatisFiyati>';

$info1 = extract_unit($data1, $string_one1, $string_two1);

$info1 = duzenL($info1);

echo $info1;

?>
```

This process.php echos only the scraped data from the first tags. But I have 30 same tags in that url and I need to scrape them all.

How can I retrieve datas between all same "SatisFiyati" and "/SatisFiyati" tags in one url?

Comment: Try using DOM parsing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of processing the raw text, use a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to load the xml from the remote site. You can then extract all [elements by tagname](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) similar to the example:

```
<?php
include 'function.php';

// Connect to this url using CURL

$url1 = 'http://www.remixon.com.tr/remixon.xml';
$data1 = LoadCURLPage($url1);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($data1);
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('SatisFiyati');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // do something with the data here
    echo $item->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all()` which returns all matches for a regular expression.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

In your case, your function `extract_unit()` would be something like:

```
function extract_unit($string, $start, $end)
{
    preg_match_all("/" . $start . "([^<]*)" . $end . "/", $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

`$matches[0]` contains array of strings that matched full pattern, and `$matches[1]` contains array of strings enclosed by tags. So you actually need `$matches[1]`.